# mlockall(): cannot allocate memory

Tags: ubuntu, preempt-rt

I am getting the error:
mlockall failed: Cannot allocate memory
when calling the function mlockall():

```
if(mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE) == -1) {
            printf("mlockall failed: %m\n");
            exit(-2);
    }
```

IDE used: Eclipse
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Real time extension using : 4.11.12 rt-15 (preempt patch)
Note : I am trying to so a UDP CONNECTION in realtime (using intel i210 ethernet controller).

When i debug the same in eclipse this is what is showing:

Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-bfm8X4/glibc-2.23/misc/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

How to solve this?

Comment: I have this : `Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-p3Km7c/glibc-2.24/io/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.` for a different problem, only when I execute the built program from the IDE in debug mode. From the console, it works. So it seems it is related only to the IDE configuration and not to our applications

Answer (score 7):

As [man 2 mlockall](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall) explains you don't seem to have the permissions to lock the amount of memory that you tried to lock. You can either adjust that limit, or try and run your program as root, e.g. via `sudo`. I don't recommend doing the latter for anything other than finding out if the limits are really the problem, so here's how to adjust the limits for bash on Kubuntu - it could work differently on your distro.

First, let's see what your limit is:

```
$ ulimit -a | grep locked
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
```

64 kbytes isn't a lot! There's a shorthand, for this, too:

```
$ ulimit -l
64
```

More than likely you won't be able to adjust the limit easily:

```
$ ulimit -l 1000000
bash: ulimit: max locked memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

And even if you were, it wouldn't persist across shell invocations, reboots etc. So we need a different approach.

`/etc/security/limits.conf` to the rescue! This is the file the default values for the limits are read from when a user session is started - see [man 5 limits.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf).

Add the following line (`nobss` is my user name, you should use yours, obviously)

```
nobss - memlock 1000000
```

to the file to set both the hard and soft limits to 1000000 kbytes. Log out and login in, and voilà:

```
$ ulimit -l
1000000
```

That's better. Unless your program uses heaps of memory this limit should do - in fact it's more than enough in most cases.